# Cordova changes the colors of my app on Android. It looks like it uses its own dark mode

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, material-ui

I'm using Material UI with React and hoping to make an Android release with Cordova.

I run:

```
cordova create appname
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

The www directory is a symlink to the build directory in my project.

When I run it in an Android emulator, the app is using its light colours and everything looks fine. If I create the apk and install it to my own device, the colours look different. Some are inverted and some look much darker than they should. The login screen which should only ever be light is also dark.

The thing is my app already has dark mode detection built in which I want to prefer over Cordova changing the colours itself.

First image is how it looks like with the Cordova generated APK. Notice how the text colours are inverted and tabs almost invisible.

Second image is how it should look. Notice the colours of the text are correct and there is a lot more contrast in the tabs.

[image: broken]

[image: normal]

I can't find any documentation about a dark mode being built into Cordova or any evidence of this happening to someone else, so I can't quite understand why it's being changed.

Another thing I've noticed is that if I install it as a PWA or open it in Chrome, it properly changes theme based on the device preferences.

If I set my device to light mode, the Cordova build shows my app's dark theme. If I set the device to dark mode, it does the forced dark theme that changes all my colours on top of dark mode.

This is the contents of my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app.platelet.platelet" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>platelet.app</name>
    <description>platelet dispatch for blood bikes</description>
    <author email="info@platelet.app" href="https://platelet.app">
        platelet.app
    </author>
    <content src="/" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <!--
            ldpi    : 36x36 px
            mdpi    : 48x48 px
            hdpi    : 72x72 px
            xhdpi   : 96x96 px
            xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
            xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
        -->
        <icon src="icon/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="icon/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="icon/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="icon/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="icon/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="icon/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

The device I'm testing on is a Xiaomi Mi 9T with Miui 12.1.4.0 (Android 11).

Thanks!

Comment: This wouldn't be in cordova itself, but in one of the layers above it. Cordova just has a webview, and that webview doesn't specify any theming / `prefers-color-scheme` out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add:

`<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />`

to `<head>` in index.html

Answer (score 0):

It is important that the theme of the app is DayNight Theme, which means it supports light or dark or auto.

> Although it depends on Android Version. A plugin might be necessary.
>
> See:
> https://github.com/timbru31/cordova-plugin-android-dark-mode-support#attention-for-sdk--33--android-13

This can be set using this cordova config.xml line:

```
<preference name="AndroidPostSplashScreenTheme" value="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
```

Also the app html meta header should be set to signal that the webview supports parent theme inheritance, this does disable the auto Dark feature, since the webview signals that dark and light themes are supported on the app, meaning are managed by your CSS rules.

For example if by default your app is a light theme but can also use a dark theme then use this html meta:

```
 <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
```

Then it is important that your css is theme aware, this is done using the media prefers-color-scheme.

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  ...
}
```

Other ways are possible, like adding a "theme-dark" class to html and define dark css rules, you can assign this class when event changes of theme preference are changed like:

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => {
 if (e.matches) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.add('theme-dark')
 } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.remove('theme-dark')
}
})
```